# Something went wrong error showing on Cashfree Payment gateway

Tags: magento2

i am using Magento 2.2.5, after successful installation Cashfree Payment gateway. when i try to checkout using cahsfree it showing an error called **Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDCQr.png

Comment: Please can you describe the issue in more detail?

Comment: Hi, after successful integration of cashfree payment gateway using Module provided by cashfree Provider, in admin dashboard it showing the field to enter the key integration. after entered when i try to pay using cashfree payment method it showing an error  **Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.**  

i am using Magento 2.2.5, after successful installation Cashfree Payment gateway. when i try to checkout using cahsfree it showing an error called Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later. https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDCQr.png can you help me to rectify the issue?.